# Passing regular files only to `sed -i`

Tags: sed, files, wildcards

I am using GNU sed 4.2.2 and after searching cannot find out the reason `sed` behaves oddly in some situations:

I have a directory with the following:

```
foofile.txt
barfile.txt
bazfile.txt
config/
```

#### Case 1

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *.txt
```

This works as I expect.  It replaces all the "foo"s with "bar"s in the three regular files.

#### Case 2

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *
sed: couldn't edit config: not a regular file
```

It replaces "foo" with "bar" in `barfile.txt` and `bazfile.txt`, but not in `foofile.txt`.  I assume it goes through the list of files expanded from the `*` alphabetically, and when it hits `config/` it errors and exits.  Is there a way to have `sed` ignore errors and continue processing files?

#### Case 3

```
for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' <"$file"; done
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
```

Could someone please explain why `sed` does this?  Why does it say there's no input file when it's being given one?

I know that I can use the following but I'm asking why sed acts this way, not how do I solve this one use case.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normal behavior. In both cases `sed` exits with `error code 4`... per `info sed`:

```
4
     An I/O error, or a serious processing error during runtime,
     GNU 'sed' aborted immediately.
```

and in both cases the messages are self-explanatory. Not sure what's unclear but for the record: the first time it errors out because it cannot edit a directory and the second time it complains because it cannot edit `stdin` in-place, it needs a file (i.e. remove that redirect before `$file`)
The proper way to do this with `find` is, as you noted, via `-exec ...`
With globs, you'll have to use a loop and test if input is a regular file before running `sed`. Or, if you're a `zsh` user, you can simply do:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *(.)
```

Comment: I think I understand how Case 3 is working now thank you.  Do you know how to make `sed` continue even if it encounters an error like in Case 2?

Comment: @Linoob - no; I think the man page is pretty clear: _"GNU 'sed' aborts immediately"_

Answer (score 7):

- Case 2:

  Avoid that directory with `find`:

  ```
    sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
  ```
- Case 3:

  The problem is the `<"$file"` in the loop, that turns the file into a stream so `sed` never sees a filename.  Just remove that `<`:

  ```
    for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do 
        sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' "$file"
    done
  ```